# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to learn react and I'm not understanding this error. If I return a string it's fine but if I return  it keeps giving me this error.

|
|
|
|
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

MapsContainer.js

```
import {GoogleMapReact, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Map} from 'google-map-react';
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class MapsContainer extends Component {

    static defaultProps = {
        center: {lat: 23.2341, lng:5.12342},
        zoom: 8
    }

    render() {
      
        
    return(

        <div>
            <GoogleMapReact
                bootstrapURLKeys={{key: 'kjk'}}
                defaultCenter={this.props.center}
                defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
            > </GoogleMapReact>


        {/* <GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={{
            key: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
            libraries: ['places', 'directions']
          }}
          defaultZoom={11}
          defaultCenter={{ lat: 12.2341, lng: 23.31234 }}
          yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals={true}
          onGoogleApiLoaded={({ map, maps }) => this.apiHasLoaded(map, maps)} // "maps" is the mapApi. Bad naming but that's their library.
        >
        </GoogleMapReact> */}
        

        </div>
    
    

       
 
        
    );
    }
 };

 export default MapsContainer;
```

... App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './beer.svg';
import './App.css';
import MapsContainer from './containers/MapsContainer';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">


      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      </header>

      
      <MapsContainer/>
      


    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: elaborate the error log. The error is not clear. Tip: never post your API_KEYS publicly (better delete it)

Comment: Where are you rendering App? You don't seem to be exporting anything from App.js, are you calling ReactDOM.render() in that same file?

Comment: im not getting any errors while compiling the code.. it's just giving me that error in the webpage and it's serve locally

Comment: Maybe you forgot `export default App`?

Comment: no i have that i just forgot to paste it in here

Comment: If you're looking to make a react google map quick app follow a tutorial if you are just learning. This is a good place to start: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pf7g32CwX_s

Comment: yea i'm looking to make it in a separate component but it's not exporting properly

Answer (score 0):

i finally figure it out i can't do

import {GoogleMapReact, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Map} from 'google-map-react';

instead it has to be

import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';